# Add Remove Class Reverse Siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script below that works when div status is before the span. It doesn't work when I put the span before the div. How do I change the script to make it work when I want to reverse the order of the siblings?

```
$('.status:contains("1") + span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o faa');
```

Comment: Can you show some more code e.g. your HTML?

Comment: `+` and `~` only work when the element is a later sibling of the first element. You can't go back or up the DOM tree. To do what you need try `prev()`

Comment: You have used an adjacent sibling selectors ( `+` )  which checks the _next_ element. So far there is no CSS selector (yet) that looks to previous element ... What you can do is to select the parent and check its children.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) which targets the immediately preceding sibling

```
$('.status:contains("1")').prev('span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o faa');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same code irrespective of the order of status `div` and `span` you can use following code:
**Please note it will work only if there is only a single span sibling for status**

```
$('.status:contains("1")').parent().find(" > span").removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o faa');
```

If you only want to handle the case when `span` comes before status `div`, then you should use `prev` as mentioned in other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need. I looks at all siblings of the same parent. In the example below it filters for the span.

```
$('.status:contains("1")').siblings('span').removeClass('fa-times-circle').addClass('fa-sun-o faa');
```